# How to work around keyboard layouts requiring Alt key which are also keyboard shortcuts in LibreOffice?

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice, keyboard-layout

In LibreOffice Writer, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is the shortcut to activate the *Edit* menu, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> for *Table* menu and so on.

I have a Dell Inspiron 3520. The layout I normally use is English (US). The one that I'm looking to use is Hindi (Bolnagri); which requires me to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key along with various letter keys regularly. It doesn't work, because <kbd>Alt</kbd> + many of these letters are shortcuts in LibreOffice Writer.

I want to disable these shortcuts. How do I achieve it? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 in case it matters.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely delayed response and thanks for replying. I normally use English, but I want to use Ubuntu's Hindi keyboard, which requires me to use the Alt key along with various letter keys regularly. It doesn't work, because Alt+ many of these letters are shortcuts.

Comment: I have a Dell Inspiron 3520. The layout I normally use is English (US). The one that I'm looking to use is Hindi (Bolnagri)

Comment: As I have checked `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in` keyboard definition. `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` meaning it uses Right Alt (Alt Gr) to input 3rd position char where Left Alt (Alt) is used for shortcuts. I have tested it in 14.04. Is it same case for you in 12.04?

Comment: Yes, that worked (very strange that I didn't try that :-P). Thank you!

Comment: I have written it as answer, I would ask you to put some time to review it, then accept it or give me a feedback to improve it. See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

As I have checked `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in` XKB symbols definition for Bolnagri Hindi alternative. It does include `level3(ralt_switch)`

ie. it uses **Right Alt** (<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>) to input 3rd position/level char where Left Alt (<kbd>Alt</kbd>) is used for shortcuts.

This applies for most keyboard layouts with extended symbols map. No need to remap shortcuts involving Alt key.